# Enable hardware video decoding in VLC on Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye

Tags: hardware, video

As the title says: How can I enable hardware video decoding in VLC (or other player) in Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye?

I'm on a Raspberry Pi 3B+. Video playback in OSMC is smooth but in Raspberry Pi OS it stutters terribly in both vlc and mpv when played back in fullscreen mode. Omx-player has apparently been deprecated in Bullseye so that is not an option as far as I understand.

I have increased GPU RAM to 256 MB to allow for handling the 1920x1080p resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the `full KMS GL-driver` and the `Glamor` graphics acceleration in `raspi-config`->`Advanced` will get you 720p H264 video playback in fullscreen. I do not know if it decodes H264 though.